# Making Grid Layout work in Internet Explorer

Tags: css, internet-explorer-11, internet-explorer-9, grid-layout

I'm trying to make grid layout work in IE. It's a fairly simple grid layout, I think, that uses grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(#px, 1fr)) along with grid row/column gap.

I tried the following but it didn't work on IE11 and IE9.

```
.grid {
  display: -ms-grid;
  display: grid;
  -webkit-box-pack: start;
  -ms-flex-pack: start;
  justify-content: start; 
  margin-top: -20px;
}
```

I'm sharing my code below.

CSS code

```
.grid {
  display: grid;
  justify-content: start; 
  margin-top: -20px;
}


@media (min-width: 800px) {
  .grid {
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(270px, 1fr));
  grid-row-gap: 70px;
  grid-column-gap: 40px;
  } 
}


@media (min-width: 600px) and (max-width: 799px) {
  .grid {
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(200px, 1fr));
  grid-row-gap: 40px;
  grid-column-gap: 30px;
  margin-top: -15px;
  } 
}


@media (max-width: 599px) {
  .grid {
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(140px, 1fr));
  grid-row-gap: 40px;
  grid-column-gap: 20px;
  margin-top: 18px;
  } 
}


.grid .photo {
  width: 100%;
  background-size: contain;
  background-position: center;
}

.grid .photo:after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  padding-bottom: 100%;
}

.grid a {
  display: block;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: inherit;

}
```

HTML code

```
<div class="grid">

  <article> 
    <a href="#">
      <div class="photo" style="background-image: url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/qxeUf.jpg?s=96&g=1;"></div>
    </a>
  </article> 
  
    <article> 
    <a href="#">
      <div class="photo" style="background-image: url(https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/a235706e3d81b614acaec3368edfea4b?s=96&d=identicon&r=PG;"></div>
    </a>
  </article> 
  
    <article> 
    <a href="#">
      <div class="photo" style="background-image: url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/qxeUf.jpg?s=96&g=1;"></div>
    </a>
  </article> 
  
      <article> 
    <a href="#">
      <div class="photo" style="background-image: url(https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/a235706e3d81b614acaec3368edfea4b?s=96&d=identicon&r=PG;"></div>
    </a>
  </article> 
  
  </div>
```

Many thanks in advance

Comment: IE11 requires to set each element in its column/row grid cell.  and also use prefix. Use for IE11 an alternative with flex, and ie9 ?no flex nor grid avalaible.

Comment: Hey thanks. What can I do for IE9 here then?

Comment: no idea, Ie9 understands display:table, inline-block, .. and float. I do not have any IE9 left running anywhere ..

Comment: k thank you. btw given that i'm looking to use 'autofit' vs exact pixel values, what do i do? i found this article that has info on it https://css-tricks.com/css-grid-in-ie-debunking-common-ie-grid-misconceptions/ but wasn't clear what to do

Comment: auto-fit won't be avalaible for IE11 , auto sizing and repeat can be used, but wrapping into different amount of columns and row for IE11 can not.

Comment: hm ok. would you mind taking this line only --> grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(140px, 1fr));  <--  and turn it into IE code? sorry i'm pretty lost here.... and would be super thankful for your help.

Comment: you cannot, you have to think it otherwise or use flex (my first comment).

Comment: it's for screen size <599px, so i don't need different numbers of columns/rows. just need auto sizing, with column and row numbers fixed.

Comment: wait - didn't you just say "auto sizing and repeat can be used" with IE11? that's what i'm looking for

Comment: from csstrick . auto, for a column or row,  mimax() and repeat. for a screen <599 , use a mediaquerie to reset the grid and grid position ;)

Comment: thanks but would you mind writing IE code for this line only if you can do this quickly? -->  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(140px, 1fr)) <-- sorry i'm new to development :[

Comment: I read the css trick doc but wasn't sure :/

Comment: try flex like i commented at first : https://jsbin.com/zesavamufa/1/edit?css,output

Comment: I agree with the suggestion given by G-Cyrillus for adding the grid element on the grid column/ row can help to display it properly in IE 11 browser. The IE 9 browser is out of support scope of the Microsoft. I suggest you recommend your users use the latest Microsoft browsers or if that is not possible then at least move to IE 11 browser.